# Cycle java . How to get next h?

Tags: java, testing

```
private void choosePlaceForEmployee(String... param) {
    str: for (int j = 0; j <= param.length * 2 - 1; j += 2) {
        for (int h = 0; h <= param.length - 1; h++) {
            ts.makerNewTak().placesForWorker().get(j).click();
            ts.makerNewTak().searchForEmployee().sendKeys(param[h]);
            ts.makerNewTak().listOfAllPlaces().get(0).click();
            continue str ;
        }
    }
}
```

I made simple tests for web, and i should to click on field and write first object from my array. But after one iteration i get j=2 , *but h again=0* how to make this cycle right?

First iteration:

[image: 1 iter]

Second iteration:

[image: 2 iter]

Comment: What do you mean by "right"? You mean it doesn't get reset to 0 after each outer loop?

Comment: yes:) h should stay after each iter

Comment: `j <= something - 1` is perhaps more easily written as `j < something` (unless `something` happens to be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void choosePlaceForEmployee(String... param) {
    for (int j = 0,h=0; j <= param.length * 2 - 1; j += 2 ,h++) {
            ts.makerNewTak().placesForWorker().get(j).click();
         ts.makerNewTak().searchForEmployee().sendKeys(param[h]);
            ts.makerNewTak().listOfAllPlaces().get(0).click();

        }
    }
```

just write h in for , and just h++

Comment: This is the same as the answer I have. `j == h * 2`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't need a nested loop, rather just one loop.

```
private void choosePlaceForEmployee(String... param) {
    for (int h = 0; h < param.length; h++) {
        int j = h * 2;
        ts.makerNewTak().placesForWorker().get(j).click();
        ts.makerNewTak().searchForEmployee().sendKeys(param[h]);
        ts.makerNewTak().listOfAllPlaces().get(0).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: @СеменНемытов I suggest you remove the continue, not the loop. The way you have coded it, already removes the inner loop.

Comment: @СеменНемытов The inner loop will do that by looping each time.

Comment: if i remove continue , it will do inner cycle first , then external. I need to make external , then  inner and again

Comment: @СеменНемытов do you mean like the code I have changed it to?